# bibliographystyle{spbasic} produces author(year) references in text instead of (year, author)

Tags: natbib, bibliographystyle

For the Journal Cellulose by Springer, I need to create ciation call-outs in the body of the document in the style `(author, year)`.
Using the code below only gives me references in this way:

> Kirkegaard et al. (2017)

```
\documentclass{svjour3}                   
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
...
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{bib}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You should use the `\citep` command to create parenthetic-style citation call-outs when using the `natbib` citation management package.